# Pyspark list to Scala Sequence

Tags: java, scala, arraylist

I have scala class that accepts one argument that is Pyspark List.

It works with ArrayList but it does not with Sequence.

My code is:

```
class HelloWorld(x: Seq[String]) {
    val elo = x
    ...
```

In Pyspark I do:
elo = sc._jvm.HelloWorld(["A", "B"]).someMethod()

The error i get is

```
py4j.Py4JException: Constructor com.matching.HelloWorld([class java.util.ArrayList]) does not exist
```

So, I do in Scala `import java.util.ArrayList` and it works but I want to avoid Scala type: Sequence and avoid Java imports.

EDIT:
I see this:
https://www.py4j.org/advanced_topics.html

I know Pyspark uses Py4J to allow use Python wrappers around Java so it can use JVM...but I would expect Scala collections to be able to use ...

So, I can not use Scala Sequence?

Answer (score 0):

`import scala.collection.JavaConversions._;`

`x.toSeq` solves the problem.